# Can I use a variable in destructor that is not defined in the header file?

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

I have been reading this code from one of my class. And got really confused on one of the variables in the destructor. Here is the code, BTW, this is a linked list header file. And the variable I think is not defined but used is the n;

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class LinkedList
{
private:

  struct node
  {
     int info;
     node * next;
  };

  typedef node * nodeptr;

  nodeptr start;

  int count;


public:

       // Constructor

   LinkedList()
   {
      start = NULL;
      count = 0;
   }

       // Destructor

   ~LinkedList()
   {
      nodeptr p = start, n;

      while (p != NULL)
      {
         n = p;
         p = p->next;
         delete n;
      }
   }
```

The first time this n showed up is from the line
nodeptr p = start, n;
So please teach me why is it legal to use a variable like this. Any commands is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: "And the variable I think is not defined but used is the n". But that `nodeptr p = start, n;` line is the *definition* of `n`!

Comment: Both p and n is of type nodeptr, what's the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ language (just like in C) each declaration can include multiple declarators. E.g.

```
int a, b, c;
```

declares (and defines) three variables: `a`, `b` and `c` of type `int`. You can optionally add initializers to some declarators (or to all of them)

```
int a = 5, b, c;
```

Your

```
nodeptr p = start, n;
```

is exactly the same thing. It declares (and defines) two variables: `p` and `n`. `p` has an initializer, `n` doesn't. So, your assertion that `n` is "not defined" is obviously not true.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's defined.

`nodeptr p = start, n;` defined 2 variables, `p` and `n`. And `p` is initialized by `start`, while `n` is not.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly legal declare multiple variables in a single line of code. However note that in you example both start and n will be of type nodeptr. However you cannot have something like this:
int a, float b, double c; //this is illegal